# Promice with axios after redux-thunk action

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, rect

Technology: React, Redux, Thunk;
Problem: Promice after thunk action still not have data.

When my selector change, I upload new data to store, after upload I set this new data in next select (dependency selct). 
So promise execute, but still not how I want. Console response should be:

1. start
2. success
3. some data
4. some data

[image: My console.log()]

[image: My change effect]

[image: My action]

Comment: Showed the images for better readning.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your axios request is a post but you're not sending any information.
Have you tried with a get request ?
Does the response send anything ? (try to console.log the res.data.data after your post request)

Comment: With the GET request the same (there should be get request, you're right). Yes, I get data from server and put to store with reducer.